# ElasticSearch multi field search in non-nested arrays

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, match

Consider this JSON content:

```javascript
{
  students: [
    {
        student_name: aaa,
        classes: [
        {
            name: class1,
            properties: {
                id: 1
            }
        },
        {
            name: class2,
            properties: {
                id: 2
            }
        }
    },
    {
        student_name: bbb,
        classes: [
        {
            name: class2,
            properties: {
                id: 1
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

*students* is not nested. *classes* is not nested. I only want to match *student_name* *aaa* document by this below query:

```
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
         { "term": { "classes.name": "class1" }},
         { "term": { "classes.properties.id": "1" }}
         ]
      }
    }
}
```

But my query is matching both *aaa* and *bbb*, because it is considering my term statements as separate queries. How can I just match student *aaa*?

Comment: In the first part, why doesn't the number of `[`'s (3) match the number of `]`'s (1)? Shouldn't it? This doesn't appear to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make the student as a [nested type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). Otherwise it gets flattened and your query will match both the documents.

**From the same ElasticSearch documentation**:

> When ingesting key-value pairs with a large, arbitrary set of keys,
> you might consider modeling each key-value pair as its own nested
> document with key and value fields. Instead, consider using the
> flattened data type, which maps an entire object as a single field and
> allows for simple searches over its contents. Nested documents and
> queries are typically expensive, so using the flattened data type for
> this use case is a better option.

Please refer to examples given in the same documentation and it will be clear to you. When `student` is changed to `nested` you should be able to get your expected results.